# Org-mode repeating tasks with subtasks

Tags: emacs, scheduled-tasks, org-mode

Is there a way to make a repeating task or project with subtasks in org-mode that resets properly?  I want to do something like the following:

```
* TODO Weekly report
  SCHEDULED: <2013-12-29 +1w>
** TODO Ask Bob for numbers
** TODO Ask Mary for numbers
** TODO Compile report
```

However, when I mark the subtasks as complete, and then the main task,
only the main task resets as a repeating task; I then have to manually
unmark the subtasks.  However, if I add the repeating schedule to the
subtasks, they reset as soon as I mark them complete, so I cannot track
my current status on the task nor ever mark the parent task as complete.

Comment: I use checkboxes for the sub-tasks and have one at the end that reminds me to uncheck checkboxes and complete the task. Nevertheless, I agree it's not clean.

Comment: please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164918/how-to-untick-checkboxes-in-org-mode-for-the-next-cyclic-repetitive-task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just coded up a solution to this (based heavily on the `org-checklist.el` code that koushik mentioned): [`org-subtask-reset.el`](https://github.com/jezcope/dotfiles/blob/master/emacs.d/lisp/org/org-subtask-reset.el)

Basic use is as follows:

1. Download and put it somewhere in your [Emacs `load-path`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath).
2. Either:

   - `(require 'org-subtask-reset)` somewhere in your Emacs configuration; or
   - Customize `org-modules` and add `org-subtask-reset` as an external package
3. Set the `RESET_SUBTASKS` property for any task that should have its subtasks reset.

For your example, this should work:

```
* TODO Weekly report
  SCHEDULED: <2013-12-29 +1w>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :RESET_SUBTASKS: t
  :END:
** TODO Ask Bob for numbers
** TODO Ask Mary for numbers
** TODO Compile report
```

Comment: Very nice, I'll give it a try once I have some time.

Comment: This works for me, but I find it to be very slow on .org files with many tasks. A task which is not set to reset_subtasks will still take a very long time to move to the DONE state.